# What does the medical cross symbol over a room mean?

Tags: two-point-hospital

So I'm doing the Tumble hospital, and I've noticed that both the reception and fracture ward have a Hospital Cross with an arrow symbol over them (see below), but I'm not really sure what they mean. They've been up there for a while, and I've mostly been ignoring them, but I'm starting to worry there indicating an issue I should fix.

[image: health icon]

What does the cross symbol over a room indicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [Steam Posting](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1500641388), this means a High Priority room:

> Green plus symbol means you made that into a high priority room so it will always be staffed before others.

It looks like this means that these kind of rooms will be staffed first over other rooms.  Also according to the post, you can remove this effect by:

> You can undo that by clicking on the room, and on the window that appears, you will have "Low" on the very right. If you click on it , your room will be back to normal priority.